# Ajax content type Unicode issue

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, unicode

**we have a string česko**
Here is code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: stringUrl,
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(response) {
        //on succes
    }
});
```

when we pass by query string we receive same string in javascript

but when we pass above mentioned string to web api controller

then instead of **česko** string we receive **?esko** string in c# code.

please help

Comment: issue was resolved using this method  var uri = "my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
var res = encodeURI(uri);

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment, you should really change:

```
var uri = "my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab"; var res = encodeURI(uri);
```

to something like this:

```
var fileName = "my test.asp";
// You can join the string literals I have below together, but I am
//   splitting them apart here for the sake of the discussion below.
var res = fileName + "?" + "name" + "=" + encodeURIComponent("ståle") +
            "&" + "car" + "=" + encodeURIComponent("saab");
```

My above code assumes that the variable *names*, `name` and `car`, are ASCII-only as is `fileName`. If you may have non-ASCII characters in your `fileName`, you should use `encodeURI` on it (since it should not have the "?" character to start a query string yet), whereas if the variable *names* like "name" and "car" actually have non-ASCII characters, you should use `encodeURIComponent` on them (but not on the "?", "&", and "=" characters included in my code).

The reason you need `encodeURIComponent()` on your non-ASCII portions is because that will ensure that characters like "=", "&", and "?" are escaped rather than allowed to split up your query string.